# How to download facebook image from url

Tags: python, image, facebook

I want to write a python code that downloads images from urls from a facebook page to my device or drive.

I have urls like these in my data.

https://www.facebook.com/unicef/photos/a.10150563250124002/10159465029074002/?type=3

but their expanded urls don't result in .jpg,.png images. Instead they direct us to a page that contains the desired image.

How do I download images from these urls?

Comment: What is your current code that you developed? What are the problems you face with?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `requests` module for this.

```
import requests # to get image from the url
import shutil # to save it locally in system
url = "https://www.facebook.com/unicef/photos/a.10150563250124002/10159465029074002/?type=3"
filename = url.split("/")[-1] # this will spilt the file name from the url
r = requests.get(url, stream = True) #getting the image, returning stream content 
r.raw.decode_content = True #decoding content to ensure the actual file size remains as it is(if this is set to false the file size might get zero)
# opening the image
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

**OR**

I just found out, you can use `wget` also

```
#import wget python module. install it if not present
import wget

# Set up the image URL
url = "https://www.facebook.com/unicef/photos/a.10150563250124002/10159465029074002/?type=3"

# Use wget download method to download specified image url.
image_filename = wget.download(url)
```

I hope any of this helps.